# Firefox: How does one 'pin' the coloring of elements, their magins, and their paddings when focus leaves the element?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When hovering over an HTML element in the Firefox inspector, in colors that element, that element's padding, and that element's margin, in the viewport.  It's pretty handy.

For example:

[image: example-of-firefox's-inspector's-element-coloring.png]

As soon as you stop hovering over that element in the inspector, the coloring goes away.

How do you "pin" that coloring so that you can mouse away from the element in the inspector, and still have it be colored?

That would be super useful, for example, when scrolling the viewport, adjusting the page's zoom level, taking a quick look at one of the other inspector tabs, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This used to be the default behavior of the highlighter (highlighter is what this box-model regions coloring is called). When you'd select a node in the inspector, the highlighter would stay visible.
This was changed a couple of years ago because it was getting in the way.

Now, I agree this may, in some cases, be very useful, and there are in fact still a couple of ways you could achieve this:

- The `highlight` command: press shift+F2 to bring up the command line tool and use the `highlight` command. This command works with a CSS selector. In your screenshot, you have selected the element with id `question-form`. With the command, you could do this: `highlight #question-form`. The command supports a variety of very useful arguments to show/hide the guides, the node infobar, choose the color, choose which box-model region you want to see, etc... (type `help highlight` for more info).
- The rule-view css selector highlighter: in the inspector, the sidebar that contains the CSS rules that apply to the selected element is called the rule-view. In this view, every time you see a selector, there's an icon next to it. Clicking on this icon will lock the highlighter on all elements that match this selector. This serves a slightly different purpose but is equally useful, especially when you're not sure which elements a given rule applies to.

Comment: Note that there's also a [request to add a sticky mode to the highlighter](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1376205) (in addition to the normal volatile highlighter).